# NLog not outputting anything to console

Tags: visual-studio-code, nlog

I'm following this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jn6X-rx78ZU&list=PLJFgzBCcspK8p7Hxu2OLh-f-x0PBsIGjH&index=15&ab_channel=TheTutorialChef
and I'm trying to run the server at the end. NLog should output to console that server has started, but NLog is not outputting anything. I added the NLog config file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">

    <!-- optional, add some variables
  https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#variables
  -->
    <variable name="myvar" value="myvalue"/>

    <!--
  See https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
    <targets>

        <target name="Console" xsi:type="Console" layout=" ${level} ${date} ${message} ${exception:innerFormat=Message,StackTrace}" />

        <!-- https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ColoredConsole-target -->
        <target name="CConsole" useDefaultRowHighlightingRules="true" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" layout="${logger} ${level} ${date} ${message} ${exception:innerFormat=Message,StackTrace}" >

        </target>

        <target name="warnfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/Logs/warning.txt"
                maxArchiveFiles="4"
                archiveAboveSize="10240"
                archiveEvery="Day" />

        <target name="infofile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/Logs/info.txt"
            maxArchiveFiles="4"
            archiveAboveSize="10240"
            archiveEvery="Day" />

    </targets>

    <rules>
        <!-- add your logging rules here -->

        <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" maxlevel="Warn" writeTo="infofile" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Warn" writeTo="warnfile" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="CConsole" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

But nothing outputs. There are no compilation errors or warnings. What have I done wrong? I'm using VSCode 2017, and NLog 4.7.6. I've tried editing the cofig file in the .nuget package directly. I've tried reinstalling NLog to get the original NLog.config, but now when I reinstall NLog, the config file doesn't appear in the root directory again.

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting The usual problem is forgetting to copy the NLog.config to output-folder. The other problem is people using the broken nuget-package NLog.config - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Config/

Comment: Thanks so much! I forgot to set "Copy If Never"

Comment: @TLiu, in my case I needed to put "copy always". Thank you for your help.